# How to organize header files in a library

Tags: c, header-files

Say I am writing a small libary in *C*, with most of the source code in two folders `src/A` and `src/B`, and where the header file `src/A/a.h` needs to include `src/B/b.h`. When writing code for a non-library project, I usually write

```
#include "B/b.h"
```

in `a.h` and use the `-Isrc` flag to tell the compiler where to look for header files.

Now suppose that my library is installed locally at `~/mylib` and that I want to use functions from `a.h` from a different project. Simply including that file using

```
#include "~/mylib/src/A/a.h"
```

would not work, because `~/mylib/src/B/b.h` might not be part in the search path. My question is about the canonical way to solve this issue. It's probably quite basic, but I haven't done any advanced programming in *C* and have been unsuccessful in my attemps to find a solution online.

Possible solutions I thought of are the following:

- Add `~/mylib` to the search path, but that might lead to problems if the library and client projects have header files with the same name (say `src/helpers.h`). Is it possible to include one header file without cluttering the search space with files I won't need?
- Use relative paths in the library header files, but that doesn't feel very robust.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at how other libraries do it - they either have one header file ("mylib.h") or several ("mylib/helpers.h") that are pointed at by adding appropriate -I option when compiling.

Comment: Thanks! Would you have an example of one such library? (Preferably a small one and not too difficult to understand).

Comment: All you need to understand is the file layout, but sure... "ncurses" is a library that has multiple header files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal approach is to have a separate directory specifically for the headers which form the public interface of your library. Usually this directory would be called 'include'.

You would then place the public headers for your library under a library-specific directory in there, i.e. "mylib/include/mylib/b.h". This extra 'mylib' directory prevents clashes if you're using some other library that also has a "b.h". You can also, if you wish, keep other private headers, which do not form the public interface of your library, under the 'src' directory instead, to stop them being exposed to users of the library.

This means a user of the library can then use "-I mylib/include" to include this directory, and include the individual files with, for example, "#include "mylib/b.h".

Comment: Sean, what do you think about having a mylib/include/mylib folder with symbolic links to header files, when you have a complex hierarchy with several header folders?

Answer (score 2):

Why aren't you using the standard implementation?  Break out into header and source files into their own directories.  Add `#define` headers to avoid multiple includes or namespace corruption.

Here is your directory structure:

```
~/mylib/headers/a.h
                b.h
~/mylib/src/a.c
            b.c
```

Now `a.h` will have at the very top of the file...

```
#ifndef __A_H__
#define __A_H__
    //  code

#include "~/mylib/headers/b.h"

    // end of file
#endif
```

Now `b.h` will have at the very top of the file...

```
#ifndef __B_H__
#define __B_H__
    //  code

    // end of file
#endif
```

Then just compile. `gcc -I~/mylib/headers`

If you have 2 `helpers.h` just change the `#define __HELPERS_H__` in one of the files to something else like `#define __HELPERS2_H__`

Comment: How is specifying the full path when doing `#include` standard? It's not very flexible or portable. And doesn't make sense since you're also using `-I` to specify the path to the headers anyway.

Comment: Yeah, the normal approach is to have a separate headers directory (more usually called 'include', and you would have your headers under a library-specific directory in there, i.e. "mylib/include/mylib/b.h". This means you can then use "-I mylib/headers" then include with "#include "mylib/b.h". The extra 'mylib' directory to prevent clashes if you're using some other library that also has a "b.h".

Comment: My apologies.  I was using the full path for illustrative purposes.  But you are correct.  Do not use the full path.